# how to convert latin1 charset client-sent character to utf8mb4

Tags: php, mysql, shared-hosting

I host my website on iPage shared hosting. I do not have root privileges so i cant configure mysql enviroment variables. that particulat variables are these

[image: those vars]

when i try to pull data (i.e. text containing these characters: čćžšđ) from the database that are not from latin1 charset i get ? rendered on my website, but on my localhost xampp server (where these variables are utf8mb4 instead of latin1) no problems occur

reminder: this database's collation is utf8mb4_general_ci, and mentioned characters ARE PROPERLY STORED, only when retreiving data the problem occurs

since I cant change these variables (shared hosts dont get root privileges, in this case mysql SUPER privilege) i need a workaround, any suggestions?

Comment: Execute `SET NAMES utf8mb4` when you connect. You don't need special privileges to set session options. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-names.html for details.

Comment: Works!, Thanks @BillKarwin, you can write an answer so I can flag it, thanks again, it was a huge struggle solved with one line of code/query!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SET NAMES utf8mb4` to set the client & connection character set. You can do this as a session setting immediately after you connect. You don't need global privileges to do this.

Some connectors even provide a built-in way to do this, so check the documentation for the connector you use.